# hosting backend api on nginx

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

i want to configure my backedn api on nginx with my doamin like https://example.com/api

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    server_name example.com;

    location /admin-dashboard/ {
        alias /home/bitnami/admin-dashboard/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin-dashboard/index.html;
    }

    location / {
        root /home/bitnami/frontend/out;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://publicip:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

but its not working when i hit https://example.com/api/admin/login on postman api it dosent generate any token but when i hit http://publicip:4000/admin/login it works

i have tried changing server blocks clearing cache on node its not working also my backend is running through pm2

Comment: What *does* it do when you hit the example.com variant?

Comment: dispalys my main frontend website

Comment: It does that when you access `https://example.com/api/admin/login`?

Comment: no /api is my backend so it dosent show anything on browser but when i use it on post man it should generate token it dosent do that

Comment: OK, so again, what *does* it do when you issue the Postman request? Do you get a 404? An error? A blank page? Anything in your logs?

Comment: shows 404 error

Comment: Is it Nginx's 404, or the proxy's?